# Xml over tcp without message frame

Tags: c#, xml, tcp

I have to implement a tcp connection where raw xml data is passed.
Unfortunately there is no message framing, I now this is realy bad, but I have to deal with this...

The Message would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DATA></DATA>
```

or this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DATA />
```

Now I have to receive messages that could have self closed tags. The message is always the same, it is always like xml description and a data tag with inner xml that is the message content.
So if it would be without self closed tags, this would be easy, but how can I read both?

By the way I am using the TcpListener.

Edit :
Everything is fine if there is no self closed tag.

```
            if (_clientSocket != null)
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
                _clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 100; // 1000 miliseconds

                while (_continueProcess)
                {
                    if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        bool isMessageComplete = false;
                        String messageString = String.Empty;
                        while (!isMessageComplete)
                        {
                            var bytes = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            try
                            {
                                int bytesReaded = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int) _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                                if (bytesReaded > 0)
                                {
                                    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesReaded);
                                    messageString += data;

                                    if (messageString.IndexOf("<DATA", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0 &&
                                        messageString.IndexOf("</DATA", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
                                    {
                                        isMessageComplete = true;
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            catch (IOException)
                            {
                                // Timeout  
                            } 
                            catch (SocketException)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Conection is broken!");
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                } // while ( _continueProcess )
                networkStream.Close();
                _clientSocket.Close();
            }
```

Edit 2 (30.03.2015 12:00)

Unfortunately it is not possible to use some kind of message frame.
So I ended up to use this part of code (DATA is my root node):

```
            if (_clientSocket != null)
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
                _clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 100; 
                string data = string.Empty;

                while (_continueProcess)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
                        {

                            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                            sw.Start();
                            var bytes = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];

                            int completeXmlLength = 0;
                            int bytesReaded = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int) _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            if (bytesReaded > 0)
                            {
                                message.AddRange(bytes);
                                data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesReaded);

                                if (data.IndexOf("<?", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
                                {
                                    if (data.IndexOf("<DATA", StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0)
                                    {
                                        Int32 rootStartPos = data.IndexOf("<DATA", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                                        completeXmlLength += rootStartPos;
                                        var root = data.Substring(rootStartPos);
                                        int rootCloseTagPos = root.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                                        Int32 rootSelfClosedTagPos = root.IndexOf("/>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                                        // If there is an empty tag that is self closed.
                                        if (rootSelfClosedTagPos > 0)
                                        {
                                            string rootTag = root.Substring(0, rootSelfClosedTagPos +1);
                                            // If there is no '>' between the self closed tag and the start of '<DATA'
                                            // the root element is empty.
                                            if (rootTag.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0)
                                            {
                                                completeXmlLength += rootSelfClosedTagPos;
                                                string messageXmlString = data.Substring(0, completeXmlLength + 1);
                                                data = data.Substring(messageXmlString.Length);
                                                try
                                                {
                                                    // parse complete xml.
                                                    XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(messageXmlString);
                                                }
                                                catch(Exception)
                                                {
                                                    // Invalid Xml.
                                                }
                                                continue;                                               
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (rootCloseTagPos > 0)
                                        {
                                            Int32 rootEndTagStartPos = root.IndexOf("</DATA", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                                            if (rootEndTagStartPos > 0)
                                            {
                                                var endTagString = root.Substring(rootEndTagStartPos);
                                                completeXmlLength += rootEndTagStartPos;
                                                Int32 completeEndPos = endTagString.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                                                if (completeEndPos > 0)
                                                {
                                                    completeXmlLength += completeEndPos;
                                                    string messageXmlString = data.Substring(0, completeXmlLength + 1);
                                                    data = data.Substring(messageXmlString.Length);
                                                    try
                                                    {
                                                        // parse complete xml.
                                                        XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(messageXmlString);
                                                    }
                                                    catch(Exception)
                                                    {
                                                        // Invalid Xml.
                                                    }                                                           
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            sw.Stop();
                            string timeElapsed = sw.Elapsed.ToString();

                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        data = String.Empty;  
                    }
                    catch (SocketException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Conection is broken!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

This code I had use if ther were some kind of message framing, in this case 4 bytes of message length:

```
            if (_clientSocket != null)
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
                _clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 100; 
                string data = string.Empty;

                while (_continueProcess)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
                        {
                            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                            sw.Start();

                            var lengthBytes = new byte[sizeof (Int32)];
                            int bytesReaded = networkStream.Read(lengthBytes, 0, sizeof (Int32) - offset);
                            if (bytesReaded > 0)
                            {
                                offset += bytesReaded;
                                message.AddRange(lengthBytes.Take(bytesReaded));
                            }
                            if (offset < sizeof (Int32))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            Int32 length = BitConverter.ToInt32(message.Take(sizeof(Int32)).ToArray(), 0);

                            message.Clear();
                            while (length > 0)
                            {
                                Int32 bytesToRead = length < _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize ? length : _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                                byte[] messageBytes = new byte[bytesToRead];
                                bytesReaded = networkStream.Read(messageBytes, 0, bytesToRead);
                                length = length - bytesReaded;
                                message.AddRange(messageBytes);
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.ToArray());
                                XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Invalid Xml.
                            }
                            sw.Stop();
                            string timeElapsed = sw.Elapsed.ToString();                                
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        data = String.Empty;  
                    }
                    catch (SocketException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Conection is broken!");
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Like you can see I wanted to measure the elapsed time, to see witch methode has a better performance. The strange thing is that the methode whith no message framing has an average time of 0,2290 ms, the other methode has an average time of 1,2253 ms.
Can someone explain me why? I thought the one without message framing would be slower...

Comment: If you can't implement message framing, you need to "read until you know you read it all". How to do so depends on your current code. Show your code.

Comment: This is the problem, the code can read until I find the end tag </DATA, but if it is self closed, I cannot find it...

Comment: If there isn't framing, then the TCP data should carry length bytes preceding the actual data of interest(XML data). Can the client and server agree on that protocol?

Comment: Why can't you just handle the self-closed element tag in addition to a regular one? Barring that, you need a _proper_ XML parser, and one in which you can control the buffering (i.e. by turning it off). Frankly, the code you have might work for the examples you've tried, but I'm skeptical it's sufficiently robust as to be able to handle _any_ XML that's thrown at it. In any case, since you seem to be implementing a custom protocol, it would be better to just negotiate a change to the protocol so that your "messages" can be properly frame (e.g. preceded with a byte count, delimited, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The code above is only a simple example of what I intended.. I definitely agree with the message lenght bytes before the xml, I hope that I can convince the customer! Otherwise I think this will complicate the communication..

Answer (score 0):

Hand the `NetworkStream` to the .NET XML infrastructure. For example create an `XmlReader` from the `NetworkStream`.

Unfortunately I did not find a built-in way to easily create an `XmlDocument` from an `XmlReader` that has multiple documents in it. It complains about multiple root elements (which is correct). You would need to wrap the XmlReader and make it stop returning nodes when the first document is done. You can do that by keeping track of some state and by looking at the nesting level. When the nesting level is zero again the first document is done.

This is just a raw sketch. I'm pretty sure this will work and it handles *all* possible XML documents.

No need for this horrible string processing code that you have there. The existing code looks quite slow as well but since this approach is much better it serves no purpose to comment on the perf issues. You need to throw this away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - 3rd party system sends messages in XML format via TCP but my TCP client application may receive message partially or several messages at once. One of my colleagues proposed very simple and quite generic solution.

The idea is to have a string buffer which should be populated char by char from TCP stream, after each char try to parse buffer content with regular .Net XML parser. If parser throws an exception - continue adding chars to the buffer. Otherwise - message is ready and can be processed by application.

Here is the code:

```
    private object _dataReceiverLock = new object();
    private string _messageBuffer;
    private Stopwatch _timeSinceLastMessage = new Stopwatch();
    private List<string> NormalizeMessage(string rawMsg)
    {
        lock (_dataReceiverLock)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();


            //following code prevents buffer to store too old information
            if (_timeSinceLastMessage.ElapsedMilliseconds > _settings.ResponseTimeout)
            {
                _messageBuffer = string.Empty;
            }
            _timeSinceLastMessage.Restart();



            foreach (var ch in rawMsg)
            {
                _messageBuffer += ch;
                if (ch == '>')//to avoid extra checks
                {
                    if (IsValidXml(_messageBuffer))
                    {
                        result.Add(_messageBuffer);
                        _messageBuffer = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidXml(string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            //fastest way to validate XML format correctness
            using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml)))
            {
                while (reader.Read()) { }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Few comments:

- Need to control lifetime of string buffer, otherwise in case network disconnection old information may stay in the buffer forever
- There major problem here is the performance - parsing after every new character is quite slow. So need to add some optimizations, such as parse only after '>' character.
- Make sure this method is thread safe, otherwise several threads may flood string buffer with different XML pieces.

The usage is simple:

```
    private void _tcpClient_DataReceived(byte[] data)
    {
        var rawMsg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
        var normalizedMessages = NormalizeMessage(rawMsg);

        foreach (var normalizedMessage in normalizedMessages)
        {
            //TODO: your logic
        }
    }
```